# Unable to generate authorization code via PKCE flow for SPA

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, pkce

I created a SPA application in Azure AD and trying to generate access token via PKCE flow from postman.

I am following this msdoc : [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

To generate code, I am using below authorize endpoint as mentioned in above document like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=myclientid
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=myredirecturi
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

But I am getting error like below:

```
AADSTS501491: Invalid size of Code_Challenge parameter.
```

What is the valid value for code_challenge parameter and how to generate it?

Comment: Please check whether your code_challenge value is not exceeding 43 characters.

Comment: Yes, it's more than 43. I just gave the same code_challenge from MsDoc. How to generate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error ***"Invalid size of Code_Challenge parameter."*** usually occurs if the **`code_challenge`** is invalid. Make sure to generate a valid code_ challenge.

To generate **`code_challenge`**, you can make use of this [**tool**](https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/) like below:

[image]

***I tried in my environment and got the code value successfully including the above the code challenge value:***

[image]

Make sure to include **`origin`** header like below:

[image]

After including all the required parameters, **I was able to generate access token successfully via PKCE flow from Postman** like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just strip your hash to 43 characters. Then your fine. For example:

```
$this->code_challenge = hash("sha256", random_bytes("96"));
$code_challenge = substr($this->code_challenge, 0, 43)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using S256 (SHA256) as the code challenge method (hashing algorithm to hash code verifier). So ensure that the length of the base 64 encoded code_challenge value is 43 characters. If there is a trailing '=', strip this off (this is the padding) before setting the code_challenge query string parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

This PS code works for me.

```
# Set the length of the code verifier
        $codeVerifierLength = 64
        # Set the code verifier and code challenge
        $codeVerifier = -join ((48..57) + (65..90) + (97..122) | Get-Random -Count $codeVerifierLength | ForEach-Object {[char]$_})
        $codeChallenge = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256]::Create().ComputeHash([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($codeVerifier)))
        $codeChallenge = $codeChallenge -replace "\+","-" -replace "/","_" -replace "=",""
        # Output the code verifier
        Write-Output "Code Verifier : $codeVerifier"
        # Output the code challenge
        Write-Output "Code Challenge: $codeChallenge"

# Set the request parameters
    $params = @{
        client_id = $clientId
        redirect_uri = $redirectUri
        response_type = "code"
        response_mode = "query"
        resource = $resource
        scope = $scope
        code_challenge = $codeChallenge
        code_challenge_method = "S256"
    }
    # Build the authorization URL
    $authUrl = $authEndpoint + "?" + $(($params.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" }) -join "&").tostring()
```