My Azure AD Public Client App seems to be misconfigured
I stumbled in a azure AD authentication and authorization in NestJS, the problem is I am using a public client application with PKCE configuration, but the application keep asking for client_assertion or client_secret.
Here is my code - PublicAuthService.ts:
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PublicClientApplication, AuthenticationResult } from '@azure/msal-node';
import * as crypto from 'crypto';

@Injectable()
export class PublicAuthService {
  public pca: PublicClientApplication;
  private readonly logger = new Logger(PublicAuthService.name);
  private codeVerifier: string;  // Temporarily store the code verifier

  constructor() {
    this.pca = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}`,
      },
    });
  }

  // Helper function to generate a code verifier
  private generateCodeVerifier(): string {
    return crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('base64url');
  }

  // Helper function to generate a code challenge
  private generateCodeChallenge(verifier: string): string {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(verifier).digest('base64url');
  }

  async getAuthUrl(): Promise<string> {
    this.codeVerifier = this.generateCodeVerifier();  // Store the code verifier

    const codeChallenge = this.generateCodeChallenge(this.codeVerifier);

    return this.pca.getAuthCodeUrl({
      scopes: ['User.Read'],
      redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
      codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
      codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
    });
  }

  async acquireTokenByCode(code: string): Promise<AuthenticationResult> {
    return this.pca.acquireTokenByCode({
      code,
      scopes: ['User.Read'],
      redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
      codeVerifier: this.codeVerifier,  // Use the stored code verifier
    });
  }
}

PublicAuthController.ts:
import { Controller, Get, Query, Res, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PublicAuthService } from './public_auth.service';

@Controller('public-auth')
export class PublicAuthController {
  constructor(private readonly publicAuthService: PublicAuthService) {}

  @Get('login')
  async login(@Res() res) {
    const authUrl = await this.publicAuthService.pca.getAuthCodeUrl({
      scopes: ['User.Read'],
      redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
    });
    res.redirect(authUrl);
  }

  @Get('redirect')
  async handleRedirect(@Query('code') code: string, @Res() res) {
    try {
      const result = await this.publicAuthService.acquireTokenByCode(code);
      res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
        accessToken: result.accessToken,
        user: result.account,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  }
}

When I open http://localhost:3000/api/v1/public-auth/login the application successfully opens the Azure AD login page and prompts the user to input their username and password, but after the authentication process, it returns:

invalid_client: Error(s): 7000218 - Timestamp: 2024-10-21 02:49:19Z - Description: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
Trace ID: e76ee3c8-d591-43f5-b939-1a5188441000
Correlation ID: 3711a68c-a1c7-4ddf-a524-0fbd0d68feb2
Timestamp: 2024-10-21 02:49:19Z

As far as I know, client_assertion and client_secret are only used in confidential client application. Any guidance for this?
Edit:
When i change Platform Configuration from Web to SPA, the error changed to:

AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for
cross-origin authorization code redemption.


Enable the Public client flow to resolve the error

@Rukmini already enabled Public flow on the authentication section Azure AD

interestingly, when i changed the platform configuration from Web to SPA the error changed to:
AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599321/unable-to-generate-authorization-code-via-pkce-flow-for-spa/72599875#72599875

In pca client
this.pca = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.TENANT_ID}`,
        clientSecret: "xxx"
      },
    });

You need to add a client secret generated from the app registration in the AD.

Navigate to the app registration in the Azure portal.




Copy the value, not the secret ID, and replace it in the configuration.

